# eclipse CDT IDE think I have errors I don't when using JNI

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing using eclipse CDT and everthing is great. But since I've started using JNI, it seems like nothing will compile. Probably because I can't find the JNI.h include file.

Just to make things clear, everything works and compiles perfectly in eclipse (The make file does compile everything perfectly).

The only thing that extremely annoys me is everything related to JNI marked in red in the IDE.

[image]

The errors are : 
1. Syntax error.
2. Type "JNICALL" could not be resolved.

On the following line :

```
#include <jni.h>
```

The eclipse says : Unresolved inclusion "jni.h"

If only I could help eclipse find the file (that resides inside `$JAVA_HOME/include`)

Comment: It's an indexer problem most probably. Did you add the include paths in the Paths & Symbols project properties?

Comment: Did you add it like: `${env_var:JAVA_HOME}/include` and make sure JAVA_HOME is set and exported in the shell that is running eclipse?

Comment: Ohh, thanks. I did it like in the make file, just $JAVA_HOME/INCLUDE without the "env_var"